# This issue is regarding angular drag & drop nodes. After zoom in & out in safari brouser, image, gif & video seperates from there respective nodes

Tags: angular-material

this is regarding photo(image)

label += '';
label += `<div style="width:${width}px;height:${height}px;position: relative;">`;
//if (imgUrl)
//    label += `<img src="${imgUrl}" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>`;
//if (overlay)
//    label += `<img src="${overlay}" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>`;
if (imgUrl) {
label += `<img src="${imgUrl}" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>`;
if (overlay) {
label += `<img src="${overlay}" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;"/>`;
}
} else if (overlay)
label += `<img src="${overlay}" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>`;
if (!imgUrl && !overlay)
label += `<div style="width:100%; height:100%; background:#C4C4C4;"></div>`;

this is regarding video

label += '';
label += `<div style="width:${width}px; height:${height}px;position: relative;">`;
//if (imgUrl)
//    label += `<img src="${imgUrl}" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>`;
//if (overlay)
//    label += `<img src="${overlay}" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>`;
if (imgUrl) {
label += `<img src="${imgUrl}" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>`;
if (overlay) {
label += `<img src="${overlay}" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;"/>`;
}
} else if (overlay)
label += `<img src="${overlay}" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>`;
if (!imgUrl && !overlay)
label += `<div style="width:100%; height:100%; background:#C4C4C4;"></div>`;
label += '';
label += '';
label += `<div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden !important; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 67px !important;color:#ffffff;font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;font-family:Comfortaa;letter-spacing:0.1em;text-transform:uppercase;">${this.VideoData.Name}</div>`;
}
return label;

this is regarding gif

label += '';
label += `<div style="width:${width}px; height:${height}px;position: relative;">`;

```
        //if (imgUrl)
        //    label += `<img src="${imgUrl}" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>`;
        //if (overlay)
        //    label += `<img src="${overlay}" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>`;
        if (imgUrl) {
            label += `<img src="${imgUrl}" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>`;
            if (overlay) {
                label += `<img src="${overlay}" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;"/>`;
            }
        } else if (overlay)
            label += `<img src="${overlay}" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>`;
        if (!imgUrl && !overlay)
            label += `<div style="width:100%; height:100%; background:#C4C4C4;"></div>`;
        label += '</div>';
        label += '</div>';
        label += `<div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden !important; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 67px !important;color:#ffffff;font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;font-family:Comfortaa;letter-spacing:0.1em;text-transform:uppercase;">${this.GifData.Name}</div>`;
    }
    return label;
```

I tried to change the css regarding photo,video and gif , so that they will not seperate from their respective node after zoom in and out in safari brouser, the issue is only in safari brouser